# instagram authentication initiation error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I have been working to connect my react native app to instagram, i have implemented OAuth flow, etc, and i have given proper uri, clientID and ClientSecret, but still i get the error:

ERROR  Error initiating Instagram authentication: [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404]

i dont know where im making the mistake.

I double checked my URI , client ID and client Secret, i dont get errors in my code, still when click on the button which should initiate instagram authentication, it doesn't work.